# r reshape/pivot_wide part of dataframe in long form

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
## # A tibble: 15 × 7
##    participant.code round Index name           secs_since_round_s…   delta  data
##    &lt;fct&gt;            &lt;int&gt; &lt;int&gt; &lt;chr&gt;                        &lt;dbl&gt;   &lt;dbl&gt; &lt;dbl&gt;
##  1 0ey3b4tb             1    20 &quot;&quot;                              NA  -3.31  170. 
##  2 0ey3b4tb             1    21 &quot;&quot;                              NA  -0.127 170. 
##  3 0ey3b4tb             1    22 &quot;&quot;                              NA   6.72  177. 
##  4 0ey3b4tb             1    23 &quot;&quot;                              NA  13.1   190. 
##  5 0ey3b4tb             1    24 &quot;Trade_ends&quot;                   126   3.90  194. 
##  6 0ey3b4tb             1    25 &quot;&quot;                              NA   4.98  199. 
##  7 0ey3b4tb             2    26 &quot;Trade_starts&quot;                   0   9.18  109. 
##  8 0ey3b4tb             2    27 &quot;slider value…                   9   2.91  112. 
##  9 0ey3b4tb             2    27 &quot;show confirm…                   9   2.91  112. 
## 10 0ey3b4tb             2    27 &quot;Continue kee…                  11   2.91  112. 
## 11 0ey3b4tb             2    27 &quot;slider value…                  13   2.91  112. 
## 12 0ey3b4tb             2    28 &quot;slider value…                  16   3.41  115. 
## 13 0ey3b4tb             2    28 &quot;slider value…                  18   3.41  115. 
## 14 0ey3b4tb             2    29 &quot;sharpChangeD…                  26  11.3   127. 
## 15 0ey3b4tb             2    30 &quot;&quot;                              NA -78.9    47.9
```

This is a panel data df in long format, grouped by *participant.code*, *round* and *Index* of events within each round, but it has complicated structure: some events took place at the same time within rounds, so they have the same *Index* but different values associated with these events. Events are recorded in *name* field, e.g. four events took place at Index value 27, and two at Index value 28. Values corresponding to these events are recorded in several separate columns, such as *secs_since_round_s...* and others (not in the tibble). I want to keep this long format structure, but

1. keep the last of all repeated observations with the original *Index* within each group by *participant.code* and *round*,
2. reshape all previous observations with the same *Index* to wide format in the same row as this last observation, with variable name taken from the corresponding *name* and variable name, and value - from the relevant value in that variable. E.g., interaction of  *Continue kee..._secs_since_round_s.* should have value 11 in line 11, and *slider value..._secs_since_round_s..* should have value 16 in line 13, so that the resulting df looks like this:

```
## # A tibble: 15 × 7
##    participant.code round Index name           secs_since_round_s…   delta  data    slider value…    show confirm…       Continue kee…_secs_since_round_s…   slider_value…_secs_since_round_s… 
##    <fct>            <int> <int> <chr>      <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>                 <dbl>                           <dbl> 
##  1 0ey3b4tb             1    20 ""                              NA  -3.31  170. 
##  2 0ey3b4tb             1    21 ""                              NA  -0.127 170. 
##  3 0ey3b4tb             1    22 ""                              NA   6.72  177. 
##  4 0ey3b4tb             1    23 ""                              NA  13.1   190. 
##  5 0ey3b4tb             1    24 "Trade_ends"                   126   3.90  194. 
##  6 0ey3b4tb             1    25 ""                              NA   4.98  199. 
##  7 0ey3b4tb             2    26 "Trade_starts"                   0   9.18  109. 
## 11 0ey3b4tb             2    27 "slider value…                  13   2.91  112.  some_value_here some_value_here             11
## 13 0ey3b4tb             2    28 "slider value…                  18   3.41  115.  some_value_here                                     16
## 14 0ey3b4tb             2    29 "sharpChangeD…                  26  11.3   127. 
## 15 0ey3b4tb             2    30 ""                              NA -78.9    47.9
```

This looks like a task for pivot_wide, but the data structure is rather complex. Any suggestions how to do that?

**EDIT**
Apparently this problem is not trivial at all to handle using pre-built libraries, so eventually I used a 'brute force' solution, and reshaped my dataset using an ad hoc if-for loop. Generally, this is not an r'ish way to proceed - but conventional techniques have their natural limitations, and it looks like the problem in question is an instance of that class.

Comment: Could you provide a helpful way to recreate your data ourselves? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure - here is the sample data file: https://github.com/albelix/datasample